# Question on the proof of the existence of the covariation presented in the book of Kallenberg

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation, local-martingales

I'm trying to understand the [proof of the existence of the covariation presented in the book of Kallenberg](https://books.google.de/books?id=uL7UBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=%22First+assume+that%22+%22recursively%22+%22theorem+15.5%22&source=bl&ots=ihr4ncD_Zk&sig=u4fwUki5ZLQ0r8g1756-toegxzM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii_qaysYLQAhVED5oKHb7eDMMQ6AEIHDAA) and got some questions about the involved objects:

Let

- $T>0$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $(M_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ be an almost surely continuous $\mathcal F$-martingale on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $M_0=0$ almost surely
- $n\in\mathbb N$, $$\tau_0^n:=0$$ and $$\tau_k^n:=\inf\left\{t>\tau_{k-1}^n:\left|M_t-M_{\tau_{k-1}^n}\right|=\frac1{2^n}\right\}\wedge T\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N$$

> **Question 1**:$\;\;\;$How can we show that $\tau_k^n$ is an $\mathcal F$-stopping time for all $k\in\mathbb N$?

Now, let $$V_t^n:=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}1_{\left(\tau_{k-1}^n,\:\tau_k^n\right]}(t)M_{\tau_{k-1}^n}\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[0,T]\tag 1$$ and $$Q_t^n:=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\left|M_{\tau_{k-1}^n\:\wedge\:t}-M_{\tau_k^n\:\wedge\:t}\right|^2\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[0,T]\;.\tag 2$$

> **Question 2**:$\;\;\;$Why do the series in $(1)$ and $(2)$ converge?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** (Assume the filtration satisfies the usual conditions.) Consider, more generally, a  real-valued adapted process $X$ with $[0,T]\mapsto X_t$ continuous a.s., and a stopping time $\sigma\le T$ such that $X_\sigma=0$. Then for a fixed real $b>0$, $\tau:=\inf\{t>\sigma:X_t=b\}\wedge T$ is a stopping time.
With this fact in hand, a simple induction show that $\tau_1^n, \tau_2^n,\ldots$ are stopping times.

To prove the assertion, we can (because of the "usual conditions") assume that $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is continuous for every $\omega\in\Omega$. (Else, let $B:=\{\omega:t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ fails to be continuous at some $t\in[0,T]\}$. Then $B\in\mathcal F_0$ and $\operatorname P(B)=0$. The  process $X'_t(\omega):=1_{B^c}(\omega)X_t(\omega)$ is indistinguishable from $X$ and has everywhere continuous sample paths. The function ${\tau_k^n}'$ defined as was $\tau_k^n$ but in  terms of $X'$ will be shown to be a stopping time in what follows, and because $\operatorname P(\tau_k^n={\tau_k^n}')=1$, you see that $\tau_k^n$ is also a stopping time.) Define $Y_t:=\sup_{0\le s\le t}1_{\{\sigma\le s\}}X_s$. By path continuity, this is the same as $\sup_{0\le s\le t,s\in\Bbb Q}1_{\{\sigma\le s\}}X_s$, which shows that $Y$ is an adapted process. Finally, $\{\tau\le t\}=\{Y_t\ge b\}\in\mathcal F_t$, for each $t\in[0,T)$, so $\tau$ is indeed a stopping time.

**Q2:** Fix $n\in\Bbb N$. Each of the sums (1) and (2) has only finitely many non-zero terms, a.s., because the assumed path-continuity of $M$ implies that $\operatorname P(\cup_k\{\tau_k^n=T\})=1$. (For a sample point $\omega\in\Omega$ with $\tau^n_1(\omega)<\tau^n_2(\omega)<\cdots<\tau_k^n(\omega)<\tau^n_{k+1}(\omega)<\cdots<T$ for all $k$, the limit $\lim_{t\uparrow T}M_t(\omega)$ fails to exist.)

Comment: I think there are some slight problems: First of all, you should define $τ$ to be $$\inf\left\{t∈(σ,T]:X_t=b\right\}$$ (and we don't need the "$\wedge\: T$" part). Then, you should define $Y_t$ to be $$\sup_{s∈(σ,\:t]}X_s$$ (i.e. we don't allow $s=σ$). With these definitions we've got $$(Ω\setminus N)\cap\left\{τ≤t\right\}=(Ω\setminus N)\cap\left\{Y_t\ge b\right\}$$ where $$N:=\left\{ω∈Ω:X(ω)\text{ is not continuous}\right\}\cap\left\{X_σ\ne0\right\}$$ is a $\operatorname P$-null set and hence $$N\cap\left\{τ≤t\right\}∈\mathcal F_t$$ by $\operatorname P$-completeness of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Now, $$Y_t(ω)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\sup_{s∈[σ(ω),\:t]\:\cap\:\mathbb Q}X_s(ω)&\text{, if }ω∈\left\{σ<t\right\}\\-∞&\text{, if }ω∈\left\{σ=t\right\}\end{cases}$$ for all $ω∈Ω\setminus N$ and $t∈[0,T]$. However, we still can conclude that $Y_t$ is $\mathcal F_t$ measurable, because it is piecewise $\mathcal F_t$-measurable on the cover $Ω=(Ω\setminus N)\cap\left(\left\{σ<t\right\}\cup\left\{σ=t\right\}\right)\cup N$. What do you think?

Comment: Q2: Why does $\operatorname P(\cup_k\{\tau_k^n=T\})=1$ imply that the sums have only finitely many nonzero terms? Is your argumentation that it implies that for $\operatorname P$-almost all $\omega\in\Omega$, there is some $k\in\mathbb N$ with $\tau_k^n(\omega)=T$? If so, why exactly do we know that $\operatorname P(\cup_k\{\tau_k^n=T\})=1$?

Answer (score 0):

1. My definition of $\tau$ is correct as written: in your alteration, what is the value of $\tau$ should it happen that $X_t<b$ for all $t\in[\sigma,T]$?
   And $Y$ is defined as it should be.
2. What is $N$? I have reduced to the case in which $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is continuous for all $\omega$.
3. If $\tau_k^n(\omega)=T$ then $\tau_j^n(\omega)=\tau_k^n(\omega)$ for all $j>k$, and all of the associated terms in your sums vanish for that \omega$.
4. As I noted, if $\omega$ is such that $\tau^n_1(\omega)<\tau^n_2(\omega)<\cdots<\tau_k^n(\omega)<\tau^n_{k+1}(\omega)<\cdots<T$, then the limit $\lim_{t\uparrow T}M_t(\omega)$ fails to exist.)

Comment: [I guess you didn't intended to write this as an answer] 1. If $X_t(ω)<b$ for all $t\in(σ(ω),b]$, then $\tau(ω)=\inf\emptyset=\infty$. My problem with your $\tau$ is that if $σ(ω)=T$, then $\tau(ω)$ is not-well defined (cause it contains the expression $X_t(\omega)$ with $t>T$). And, even in your definition of $\tau$, you're looking for $t$'s which are strictly greater than $σ(ω)$, so I think we need to exclude $σ(ω)$ in the set over which the supremum in the definition of $Y$ is taken, i.e. we should define $Y_t:=\sup_{0\le s\le t}1_{\left\{\:σ\:\color{red}{<}\:s\:\right\}}X_s$.

Comment: 2. I've defined $N$. You've reduced to the case where $X$ is continuous, right, I just wanted to mention that the argumentation works without the reduction too (under the completeness assumption on $\mathcal F$).

Comment: 4. I think I figured out why $\operatorname P(\cup_k\{τ_k^n=T\})=1$: Let $ω∈Ω$ with $X(ω)$ being continuous. Then there is some $δ>0$ with $$\left|X_s(ω)-X_t(ω)\right|<\frac1{2^n}\;\;\;\text{for all }s,t∈[0,T]\text{ with }|s-t|<δ\;.$$ Let $k∈ℕ$. If there is no $t>τ_{k-1}^n(ω)$ with $$\left|X_t(ω)-X_{τ_{k-1}^n(ω)}(ω)\right|=\frac1{2^n}\;,$$ then $$τ_k^n(ω)=\inf∅=∞\;.$$ Otherwise $τ_{k-1}^n(ω),τ_k^n(ω)<∞$ with $$τ_k^n(ω)-τ_{k-1}^n(ω)≥δ$$ and hence $$τ_k^n(ω)=\sum_{i=1}^k\left(τ_i^n(ω)-τ_{i-1}^n(ω)\right)≥kδ\;.$$ Thus, if $k∈ℕ$ with $τ_k^n(ω)<T$, then $$k<\frac Tδ\;.$$ What do you think?